# Angular format date not rendering

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular's date/time formatting with this string

```
2015-01-20 16:49:07+00:00

{{ myDate | date : 'medium' }}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working? Is the original string messed up?

Comment: I just tried it with your string and it worked perfectly... If you take out the `| date ...` part and just leave it as `{{ myDate }}` what comes out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [angular date filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

You'll notice that for an [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you need a T before the time:

```
"2015-01-20T16:49:07+00:00"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p84zjy6t/

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format }}
```

To check all format options [check the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)